# @angular/pwa service worker not working on my already existing project

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to add a service worker to my (already existing) project.
but when i open the browser, i see that it doesn't get the service worker.

These are the steps i followed:

1. Running `ng add @angular/pwa --project <my-project-name>` to my project
2. Running `ng build --prod`
3. Running the app with `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<my-project-name>`

Now, the app is running, and it does get the manifest file but not the service worker:

[image]

manifest.webmanifest:

[image]

ngsw-config.json:

[image]

When i tried to do all of the steps above on a brand new project it did work and got the service worker. but not on my already existing project.

Comment: Try setting the service worker to [`registerImmediately`](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwRegistrationOptions#registrationStrategy) like this `ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' })`. If you include a third-party library that uses something like `setInterval` the SW will by default never register.

Comment: @abraham works. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the service worker to [`registerImmediately`](https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwRegistrationOptions#registrationStrategy) like this:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: environment.production,
  registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately',
})
```

If you have a third-party library that uses something like `setInterval` the service worker will never register. This is because the default `registerWhenStable` relies on [`isStable`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#is-stable-examples) which will never happen with recurring tasks.

> the application will never be stable if you start any kind of recurrent asynchronous task when the application starts (for example for a polling process, started with a setInterval, a setTimeout or using RxJS operators like interval);

Comment: I spent about 5 - 8 hours trying to make this work, searching everywhere online, and your answer was what fixed it for me. I can't begin to tell you how much I appreciate your answer here! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For angular v.11.2.12
try installing ng add @angular/pwa@12.2.2